# Find difference between two dates ignoring the year in python3

Tags: pandas, datetime, python-3.6

I am trying to find the difference between two dates ignoring the year. So lets say if I want to find the difference between 2014-01-02 and 2019-01-01 the answer should be 1 but having trouble in doing so.
**It should be the ordinal day of the year, subtracting the day of the months
won't work**

Below is the code which I have used but it didn't give me the desired result as it is taking year into consideration as well.

`data12['Dist_from_NewYear'] = data12['only_date'].map(lambda x: x.date() - public_holidays['Date'][0].date())`

```
data12['Dist_from_NewYear']

0      -1456 days
1      -1455 days
2      -1454 days
3      -1453 days
4      -1452 days
5      -1451 days
6      -1450 days
7      -1449 days
8      -1448 days
9      -1448 days
10     -1448 days
11     -1446 days
12     -1445 days
```

Comment: So, ignoring the year, how many days between Feb 27 and March 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`dt.dayofyear`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.dayofyear.html#pandas.Series.dt.dayofyear) to get the ordinal day of the year to do the calculation:

```
In[131]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[pd.to_datetime('2014-01-02', dayfirst=False)], 'b':[pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01', dayfirst=False)]})
df['diff'] = df['a'].dt.dayofyear - df['b'].dt.dayofyear
df

Out[131]: 
           a          b  diff
0 2014-01-02 2019-01-01     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', periods=10)})

print(df["date"])
print(df["date"].dt.day[3] - df["date"].dt.day[2])
```

let me know If you are facing any issue.

Comment: This won't work, the OP wants the ordinal day of the year, you're subtracting the day of the month